# 2 line text UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton and the text of the button is filled by a randomiser.
However my problem is that sometimes the number of characters in a text is too many, leading to the button now showing the whole text.

Would it be possible to check if the characters are too many and then have it drop the rest of the text to another text line? So basically having to text lines instead of one for the UIButton?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Objectivc-C**

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; // if u need
```

else use this

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[button setTitle: @"Line1\nLine2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift**

```
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 2
button.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
```

else use this

```
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
button.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
button.setTitle("Line1\nLine2", forState: .Normal)
```

**Swift3**

```
buttonName.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
buttonName.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
buttonName.setTitle("Line1\nLine2", for: .normal)
```

Comment: if u need more than 2 lines use numberOfLines = 0, have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

In the Interface Builder, change the **Line Break** mode to **Word Wrap** for the `UIButton` control:

[image]

And to center the text, make the title **Attributed** instead of Plain.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a storyboard or .xib file, click on your button and open the Attributes inspector on the right, then in the Button section, look for the 'Line Break' field. Drop this down and you will see 2 options (among others) - 'Character wrap' and 'Word wrap', these provide the functionality you are after.

alternatively In code you can use one of the following

```
[BUTTON setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]
[BUTTON setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with UILabels growing when auto layout was used rather than word wrapping. The solution was to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth to force it to wrap the text.

For a button you can do the same thing using:

```
button.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = <max width required>.
```